# Compute percentile and max value per variable

Tags: text-processing, awk, statistics

Bash Gurus, I need to compute the max and percentile numbers for each item in the list, using awk

```
aa  1
ab  3
aa  4
ac  5
aa  3
ad  2
ab  4
ac  2
ae  2
ac  5
```

Expected output

```
Item   90th percentile   max value
aa     3.8             4
ab     3.9             4
ac     5               5
ad     2               2
ae     2               2
```

How can I do this?

[my code:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322025/compute-percentile-and-max-value-per-variable#comment566154_322025)

```
 awk '{ item[$1]++; count[$1]+=$2; max[$1]=$2; percentile[$1,.9]=$2 } 
END{ for (var in item) print var,count[var],max[var],percentile[var] } '
```

Comment: What have you tried this far, and where in your code are you stuck? Best regards.

Comment: @maulinglawns have managed to get the max and count, but not the percentile

Comment: @maulinglawns

awk '{
item[$1]++;
count[$1]+=$2;
max[$1]=$2;
percentile[$1,.9]=$2
 }
 END{
 for (var in item)
 print var,count[var],max[var],percentile[var]
 }
'

Comment: For percentiles, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707705/calculating-95th-percentile-with-awk

Answer (score 3):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0):

```
$ cat my.dat | mlr --inidx --repifs --opprint stats1 -i -a p90,max -f 2 -g 1 \
  then label 'Item,90th percentile,max value'
Item 90th percentile max value
aa   3.800000        4
ab   3.900000        4
ac   5.000000        5
ad   2               2
ae   2               2
```

The `--inidx` is for positionally indexed input; `--repifs` since whitespace is repeated between columns; `--opprint` for tabular output. `stats1` aggregating p90 and max (`-a p90,max`) on field 2 (`-f 2`) grouped by field 1 (`-g 1`); `-i` for interpolated percentiles. Then `label` can be used for custom column-renames.